# I can't upload file in adonis js, move is not function

Tags: node.js, file, upload, adonis.js

I have the following file type field

```html
<form action = "javascript:;" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulario" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="span7">  
       <input type="file" multiple class="file file-loading" data-preview-file-type="any" id="fileUp" name="fileUp[]">
    </div>                                          
  </div>
</form>
```

and in the controller i have this for upload file

```
 const Helpers = use('Helpers')
    const myFile = request.file('fileUp')
    const directory = Helpers.publicPath()

    await myFile.move(directory, {
        overwrite: true
    })
```

but return error "move is not function"
i don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Your input is for multiple files (fileUp[]), the docs has a section for multiple file upload,you should use **moveAll()** instead of **move()**

```
  await profilePics.moveAll(Helpers.tmpPath('uploads'))

  if (!profilePics.movedAll()) {
    return profilePics.errors()
  }
```